# Can I change the Core Location alert message when accessing ALAssets?

Tags: iphone, alasset

I am using the ALAssets framework to access the Photo Library. The first time it's accessed, it asks the User if the app can use their Current Location, and I understand that is necessary and why.

However, in Core Location Manager, there is a purpose property, where it looks like I can customize the iPad's alert message to say why it is necessary to tap Yes. (I don't actually use location, just want access to the photo library.)

I can't seem to work out how to find out where to use this property, as the alert message comes up when I first try and enumerate the assets, and there doesn't seem to be anywhere to intercept it before the error occurs if the user says NO.

I know I can put up a notice of my own before first usage of ALAssets, in anticipation of the iPad built-in alert, but it seems slicker to change the actual iPad message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't customize this message. I suggest you will a radar with Apple, if you want to see this feature in the future.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest, before you try to access the photo library, that you create your own dummy CLLocationManager, set its `purpose`, then call its `-startUpdatingLocation`. That’ll get the system to bring up the location permissions dialog with your custom text, and the resulting app-wide location permissions ought to carry over to your ALAsset access.